# 500 error when using scrapy and chrome

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the https://experiment.com/discover website. When I go to inspect the page (specifically the infinite scrolling button, **See more projects**). I see this
[image]

when I put this into my chrome even I get

[image]

how do I get around this issue with scrapy. I want to be able to get around this issue so I can scrape the site using scrapy. I would prefer not using selenium as well.